# Homework Question: Confused about figure related to cDNA and gDNA

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, homework, cdna

[image]

what is the answer in blank?

I think the loop structure for the top blank is an intron.

I think RNA is the answer for the bottom blank, but it is cDNA, so it can't be RNA.

I cannot figure out what the question is asking. Please help me.

Comment: I think that the OP has tried to answer the question himself, so why close?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct about the top loop being the intronic region of the gene that would be spliced out of the mRNA that was used to make the cDNA and will not have complementarity to the sequence found in the cDNA.

You are also correct that because it is cDNA, then it cannot be RNA for the bottom box. Remember that the cDNA will contain what the mature, spliced mRNA contained, 5'-UTR, coding sequence, 3'-UTR and Poly-A (Poly T if this is first strand cDNA) tail, so the bottom answer is likely an exon, as there is complementarity between the genomic DNA and the cDNA at that position where the arrow pointing.